# How to make column and row as header in HiveQL

Tags: hive, header, hiveql

I've a question here about setting column and row as header in HiveQL. So, my expected output is like this (Table 1):

[image: Expected result]

But what I could do so far is just like this (Table 2):

[image: Result table]

with this query:

```
SELECT
sum(case when grade ='A' and class = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Grade_A_I',
sum(case when grade ='B' and class = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Grade_B_I',
sum(case when grade ='C' and class = 'I' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Grade_C_I',
sum(case when grade ='A' and class = 'II' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Grade_A_II', etc...
FROM
grade_table
where
    .......
```

I didn't find any references on the Internet to do this, so I'm just wondering is there any ways to achieve the Table 1 instead of Table 2?

Really appreciate any inputs from you all, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

something like this would work?

```
select 
case when class = 'I' then 'Class I'
when class = 'II' then 'Class II' end as class,
sum(case when grade ='A' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_A,
sum(case when grade ='B' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_B,
sum(case when grade ='C' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_C
from 
grade_table
group by 1
union all
select 'Total' as class,
sum(case when grade ='A' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_A,
sum(case when grade ='B' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_B,
sum(case when grade ='C' then 1 else 0 end) as Grade_C
from 
grade_table
```